# Detect if the selected Object is locked on a specific axis then run script

Tags: python

I require some help please. An object is selected. I need to detect if  that object is locked on one of the axis. Let's say the X axis. If it is locked in transforms, I want my script to run print("script"), else, if it is unlocked, I would like a different script to run. print("rest of script").

Comment: Why don't you use the `if` and `else` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The location locking property is stored in `bpy.types.Object` under the [lock_location](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object#bpy.types.Object.lock_location) attribute, which is a sequence of 3 booleans values, true if the axis is locked, false if it is unlocked.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]  # Replace with your object name
obj = bpy.context.active_object  # Use this to reference the active object (yellow outline in the viewport)

locked_axes = obj.lock_location
print([locked_state for locked_state in locked_axes])

for i, axis in enumerate(("X", "Y", "Z")):
    if locked_axes[i]:
        print(f"Axis {axis} is locked")
```

Comment: I failed to mention. The object may be a "Cube" but it may be a duplicate "Cube.001" or "Cube.002", so the script needs to detect the word "Cube.*" .  Say for example I would like to go into edit mode, if the "Cube*" is locked. If it is unlocked the "Cube*" is renamed to "Square". I hope you can help.

Comment: Do you actually need to specify an object name in your code? That sounds very specific and not reusable. IMHO it would make more sense to just get whatever object is selected or active. So instead of `bpy.data.objects["Cube"]` at line 3 I would use `obj = bpy.context.active_object` if you want to operate only on the active object. And if you want to operate on anything selected, replace it by `selection = bpy.context.selected_objects`, insert a new line just before line 5 to iterate through each object : `for obj in selection:` and increment the rest of the code.